# Big-O notation of the permutation algorithm in python itertools.permutation

Tags: big-o

I've been trying to figure out the time-complexity of the permutation problem in python. But this problem is way beyond my abilities... Could anyone help me out pls?

By the way this algorithm is the algorithm used in python's itertools.permutation method.

In a glimpse it seems like a o(n^2) but I'm not sure the time complexity of the for loop is o(n). The for loop does't seem to work linearly...

```py
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**:

Without looking too much, I should guess that the algorithm should be bounded by `O(n!/(n-r)!)`, where `n := len(interables)`, as that is how many different permutations exist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n . At most, when `r == n`, this gives `O(n!)`

Looking at a different implementation of permutation however I get a time-complexity of `O(n^r)`, which is at most `O(n^n)` when `r == n`

I'm guessing you got your Python implementation from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Doc/library/itertools.rst ? I got my result from looking at the second/simpler implementation on that page copied here below:

```py
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    for indices in product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if len(set(indices)) == r:
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

There is one `for` loop, so the complexity will by on the order of how many times you have to loop. `product` will return a generator which yields `n^r` elements based on the given parameters.

This is sub-optimal as it's calculating permutations with replacements and using an `if` to filter out to get permutations without replacements. This is where the `O(n^r)` approach comes from.

**Note:** itertools is actually implemented in C so it may use a different algorithm than what's outlined in the Python, and thus this might not accurately reflect the actual complexity of `itertools.permutation`.

Also because of generators and lazy-evaluation your program isn't hit with the time-complexity immediately when you call the permutation function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these are iterators, so let's assume you are getting the full result with 'list()'.

Permutations complexity is lower bounded by the matematical formula for number of permutations `n!/(n-r)!`, which is `n` for `r=1` and `n!` for `r=n`.

For comparison, `O(n!)` complexity is worse than `O(2^n)`, which is really bad.

In the other implementation suggested by @jmullercuber, the complexity is even worse `O(n^r)` by using `product`, and filtering results with repeating indices.